# Is it possible to replace wordpress plugin functions?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to rewrite plugin function not in a plugin, but in theme files, like functions.php?

Comment: might be able to remove the actions that they call, and then rewrite them with `remove_action()` `add_action()`

Comment: Have you considered must use plugins ... http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins ...

Comment: But is it possible to rewrite function which is in plugin?

For example: I have advanced custom fields plugin, and function `function create_fields( $fields, $post_id )` in it that I want to overwrite in other file.

Comment: Nothing is "impossible," but there are considerations that when you need to upgrade wordpress you do not want it to break. You could make your advanced function load last ... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-plugins-load-order ... or call the advanced custom fields from the theme file itself, which is the last file to load.

Comment: I understand that it can break. The order is not the matter, I need to  overwrite plugin function..

Comment: solved using `remove_all_actions( 'acf/create_fields', 10 );
add_action('acf/create_fields', 'create_fields', 10, 2);`